# CentOS 7.1 - how to install gnome commander

Tags: linux, centos, files, gnome

I have CentOS 7.1 and cant install gnome Commander. I dont see it in the **Software** module as well as `yum install gnome-commander` does note see the package. I tried RPMs from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gnome-commander but none is working. How can i install Gnome Commander?

Comment: I think you need [nux repo](http://li.nux.ro/repos.html).

Comment: Do you have rpmforge? If not follow: https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge

Answer (score 1):

You need the [epel-release](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and the [nux-dextop](https://li.nux.ro/repos.html) repositories. With CentOS 7.5, this should work:

```
yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

Then you can

```
yum -y install gnome-commander
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t look like gnome-commander is included in CentOS7, however it is included in [Nux](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/gnome-commander-1.6.4-1.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html).  Also, I hope you mean you have CentOS 7.4 because that’s the only supported minor release.